# I've tried numerous ways to fit my handle in my slider and I can't get it working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm back again for another question about my range slider. I have my range sliders the width I need , and the height. The problem I am having is with the handle size and position. I set up my handles to be higher than the the slider itself, and I have the handles at the correct positions, but I can't figure out how to make the handles fit in the slider itself without any over hang. I have searched around but found nothing workable

My CSS file is

```
div.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header {
background:#C6DC84;  
height:42px; 
}
div.ui-widget-content {
background: #D3D3D3;
height:42px;
}

div.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
background:#A18ABF;
text-decoration:none;
width:5px;
height:42px;
margin-left:-2px;
border:none;

}
```

and my Jquery is

```
$(function () {

          $("#slider-range-Monday").slider({

              range: true,

              min: 0,

              max: 24,

              values: [0, 24],

              animate: 'slow',

              slide: function (event, ui) {

                  $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

              }

          });

          $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +

            " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

});
```

I'm almost positive that I am missing something in the css.

Thanks

Comment: show us live example (jsfiddle maybe?)

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I've never done it before, so it'll take me a couple minutes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm76/Ehe3n/

Comment: You need to link jQuery to your JSFiddle.  Here's a [correctly configured fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Ehe3n/1/).

Comment: @SuperScript, thanks, I just did that now. It was my first time using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI defines a default `position:relative` and `top: -2px` to the slider handle.  All I need to do is remove it.

So I added to the CSS:

```
div.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    ...
    top: 0;    /* override jQuery UI defaults */
}
```

Here it is working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Ehe3n/4/).

Comment: Thanks! its working perfectly. I didn't even think of 'top', thanks a lot I really appreciate it. Now I got to ask another question, but I'm going to see if I can figure it out before I ask. My next thing will be adding a label to follow each handle. I've attempted it before and have failed at it. I tried making a legend appear above it, I can do it but its not spaced out properly to align with the steps.

Comment: Exactly like that. Now I know why you call yourself SuperScript...Now, if I wanted I can change the label to an image and still have the what step the handle is on appear on a label?

Comment: I tried getting the value of the slider handle into the label and can't figure it out. I've seen the solution before but not sure where, because I never bookmarked it

Comment: I understand what you did, you have been a tremendous help and I appreciate it. Can I wrap the values being presented in an image? I have been able to turn the handle into an image, if I made an image in flash and use that as a handle am I able to have the values on the image?

Comment: and another question, and I don't expect you to do all this for me but I had found code to create a legend and I am unsure of where to put it. I made a legend in flash but trying to line up the numbers are a nightmare.

Comment: I'm back again, now i'm trying to access the slider step position to an asp label in my codebehind page\